# Check the MS office files(word, excel.ppt, access etc.) are macro enabled or not using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, excel, ms-word, powerpoint

I have some Office files... .
I want to upload these files into Data Base...
Before uploading i want to check the files are macro enabled or not... 
Expecting the solution in java script...

I have tried with the following file extensions..

`".docm",".dotm",".xlm ",".xltm",".xlsm",".xla",".xlam",".pptm",".potm",".ppsm",".sldm",".ppam",".accde"`

but i need to know any other way to find the solution in JS or C#,

by processing the file content and check any programming contents inside it..

these are the codes i tried...

```
var extnsnArray=[".docm",".dotm",".xlm",".xltm",".xlsm",".xla",".xlam",".pptm",".potm",".ppsm",".sldm",".ppam",".accde"]

var extnsn = $(file).attr('extension');

if (extnsnArray.indexOf(extnsn) > -1) 
{                                      
    // file is macro enabled                        
}                                       
else
{                                                                                   
   // file is not macro enabled                           
}
```

Comment: var extnsnArray=[".docm",".dotm",".xlm ",".xltm",".xlsm",".xla",".xlam",".pptm",".potm",".ppsm",".sldm",".ppam",".accde"]
                var extnsn = $(file).attr('extension');
                if (extnsnArray.indexOf(extnsn) > -1)
                {}

Comment: i tried like this

Comment: Instead of dumping it in the comments I suggest you edit your post and actually add the code -_-

Answer (score 1):

In the case of PowerPoint, any PPTM, PPSM, POTM, PPAM file either contains macros or is some other type of file that's been given the wrong extension, in which case PowerPoint won't open it.

PPT files may or may not contain macros, making things more complicated if you need to look at them.

Comment: Is there any chance to embed malicious codes in non  macro enabled file extensions(like ".doc",".ppt",".xlsx" etc.) ?

Comment: @AJITHCHANDRAN: .doc and .ppt as well as .xls may always contain macros.

Comment: But i want to know that if i change the extension of excel file from ".xlam" to ".xlsm". is the macro code exist in the file ?

Comment: Dirk's correct about .DOC, .PPT, .XLS etc.  As to your other question, changing the extension changes nothing *within* the files. You can put a "Sugar" label on the salt shaker, but it's still going to make your coffee taste horrid.

Comment: PPA files are add-ins and contain macros by definition. PPT and PPS files *may* contain macros. The only way I know to check for that is to open them within PowerPoint and access the IDE object model to test for the presence of code modules and slides with ActiveX objects. I have no idea how you'd do this with javascript, if it's even possible at all.